# Using Rails 2.x with MS SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, odbc

Does anybody here have positive experience of working with MS SQL Server 2005 from Rails 2.x?

Our developers use Mac OS X, and our production runs on Linux.   For legacy reasons we should use MS SQL Server 2005.

We're using ruby-odbc and are running into various problems, too depressing to list here. I get an impression that we're doing something wrong.

I'm talking about the no-compromise usage, that is, with migrations and all.

Thank you,

Answer (score 8):

Have you considered using JRuby? Microsoft has a [JDBC driver for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx) that can be run on UNIX variants (it's pure Java AFAIK). I was able to get the 2.0 technology preview working with JRuby and Rails 2.1 today. I haven't tried migrations yet, but so far the driver seems to be working quite well.

Here's a rough sketch of how to get it working:

1. Make sure Java 6 is installed
2. Install JRuby using the instructions on the [JRuby website](http://www.jruby.org/)
3. Install Rails using gem (`jruby -S gem install rails`)
4. Download the UNIX package of [Microsoft's SQL Server JDBC driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937724.aspx) (Version 2.0)
5. Unpack Microsoft's SQL Server driver
6. Find sqljdbc4.jar and copy it to JRuby's lib directory
7. `jruby -S gem install activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter`
8. Create a rails project (`jruby -S rails hello`)
9. Put the proper settings in database.yml (example below)
10. You're all set! Try running `jruby script/console` and creating a model.

```
    development:
      host: localhost
      adapter: jdbc
      username: sa
      password: kitteh
      driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
      url: jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=mydb
      timeout: 5000
```

Note: I'm not sure you can use Windows Authentication with the JDBC driver. You may need to use SQL Server Authentication.

Best of luck to you!

Ben

Comment: Shouldn't it be activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter?

Comment: It worked for me at the time I wrote this, though not perfectly. Perhaps it would have worked better if I'd used the setting you suggest. I may get around to trying it. In the meantime, community wiki is turned on - feel free to edit.

Comment: Thank You so much, this worked like a charm for me. Although you would need gem 'activerecord-jdbcmssql-adapter' installed.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of running your production server on Linux have you considered to run rails on Windows? I am currently developing an application using SQL Server and until know it seems to run fine.

These are the steps to access a SQL Server database from a Rails 2.0 application running on Windows.

The SQL Server adapter is not included by default in Rails 2. It is necessary to download and install it using the following command.

```
gem install activerecord-sqlserver-adapter
--source=http://gems.rubyonrails.org
```

Download the latest version of ruby-dbi from

http://rubyforge.org/projects/ruby-dbi/

and then extract the file from ruby-dbi\lib\dbd\ADO.rb

to C:\ruby\lib\ruby\site_ruby\1.8\DBD\ADO\ADO.rb.

Warning, the folder ADO does not exist, so you have to create it in advance.

It is not possible to preconfigure rails for SQL Server using the --database option, just create your application as usual and then modify config\database.yml in your application folder as follows:

```
development:
adapter: sqlserver
database: your_database_name
host: your_sqlserver_host
username: your_sqlserver_user
password: your_sqlserver_password
```

Run rake db:migrate to check your installation. If everything is fine you should not receive any error message.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest you weigh up migrating from the legacy database. You'll probably find yourself in a world of pain pretty quickly. From experience, Rails and legacy schemas don't go too well together either.

I don't think there's a "nice solution" to this one, I'm afraid.

Comment: You're setting yourself up for worlds of pain.

Either migrate your data, or setup some sort of MySQL front-end to your MS SQL back-end, if there are other concerns you're not mentioning.

The schema Rails needs should be motivation enough.

Answer (score 1):

> Our developers use Mac OS X, and our production runs on Linux. For legacy reasons we should use MS SQL Server 2005.

We are developing on Ubuntu 8.04, but our production servers are running Linux (Centos) and we are also using SqlServer 2005.

From our experiences the initial setup and config was quite painful - it took a couple of weeks to get everything to play nicely together. However, it's all seemless now, and I find SqlServer works perfectly well.

We use the FreeTDS ODBC drivers which once configured are fine.

DO NOT run productions Rails apps on Windows - you're asking for trouble. It's fine for development but nothing more. Rails doesn't scale well on Windows platforms.

Hope that helps.