# Ruby on Rails and MS SQL EXPRESS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sql-server-2008

I want to develop a RoR application using MS SQL Express but I cannot figure out how to connect to the database. I tried

```
development:
adapter: sqlserver
database: historicDB
username: dxt
password: dxt
host: DBI:ADO:Provider=SQLNCLI;Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;InitialCatalog=historicDB;User Id=dxt;Password=dxt;
```

and

```
development:
adapter: sqlserver
database: historicDB
host: localhost\SQLEXPRESSS
username: dxt
password: dxt
```

I also installed dbi,dbd-odbc,activerecord-sqlserver-adapter but nowthing works I always get

```
   ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

on the welcome screen

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67141/using-rails-2-x-with-ms-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 3):

First, use the TinyTDS gem and consult this page on using a named instance.
https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki/Using-TinyTds

You should be able to do this:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  database: historicDB
  dataserver: localhost\SQLEXPRESSS
  username: dxt
  password: dxt
```

Comment: I didn't understand that from the Wiki. It made me think that if I needed to use a named instance, I had to specify that in a freetds.conf file. I was then struggling to find where to create it. This makes much more sense. So glad I found it.

Comment: I had to put `localhost:1433\SQLEXPRESS` as `port:` attribute didn't work

Answer (score 1):

In old docs you will find infos about using dbi and dbi-odbc, but these are outdated.

The current state of art is using the sqlserver-adapter with TinyTds:

You will find Infos how to setup here:
https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/activerecord-sqlserver-adapter/wiki

Comment: I managed to get through all the steps (devkit,odbc dsn ..) but in the end I still get   ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this in the exact same configuration that you showed above but this link may help:  http://rob-rowe.blogspot.com/2010/10/getting-rails-3-up-on-windows.html

Comment: How did you manage to install Development Kid ? I run ruby dk.rb init and it finds my install dir, then i run ruby dk.rb install and it looks it installed but when I try to install anything I get an error that required build tools are not installed

Comment: I followed these instructions: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit specifically section 4.  After I did that I was able to get it to work.

Comment: I did the same but section 5 failed

Comment: I manage to install DevKit succesfully with some effort but still ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Comment: What version of windows are you using?  Is it 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: 32bit Windows XP exactly as the tutorial

Comment: what does the .NET connection string look like for that DB?

Comment: for .NET it is Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;uid=dxt;pwd=dxt;database=historicDB. I have created a System DN called historicDB in Control Panel in ODBC for this connection string and tried using it, but no success

Comment: I tried the connection in ruby and this code return the count of record, so the ODBC alias works

require "odbc"

DSN = "historicDB"
USER = "dxt"
PWD = "dxt"

ODBC.connect(DSN, USER, PWD) do |dbh|
 dbh.run("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UsersInTime") do |sth|
   print sth.fetch[0]
 end
end

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, though I set the dynamic port manually and I know that it's not a good solution ( I found the dynamic port **SQL Server Browser** was using in my box ).

```
production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  host: 'WIN10'
  port: 53540
  database: redmine
  username: REDMINE1
  password: "redminepassword"
```